# How do I archive an Android repo?

Tags: android, git, repository, archive-tar

With the usual git repo that I created using `git clone`, I can easily use `git archive` to export it to a tar archive, in the case that I am only interested in the current snapshot and not the entire history of the git repository.
Can I do the same with an Android repo that is created using `repo init` and `repo sync`? If so how do I do it? I am not familiar with what Android `repo` script does.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a snapshot, why not simply use `tar`? (`tar` has `--exclude` pattern.)

Comment: True...just curious if there is some repo equivalent of git-archive, since git archive let us specify revision right?

Comment: It seems that `repo` is built upon git (a frontend), so I think `git archive` should just work.